# MySQL need a query using GROUP BY column_a to also ignore duplicates of column_b

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I'm trying to get a report of the unique quantities of prizes won by users. ie. How players have won all 3 prizes, how many have won 2 prizes, etc..

```
+--------+--------+
| player | prize  |
+--------+--------+
|   1    |   1    |
+--------+--------+
|   1    |   1    |
+--------+--------+
|   1    |   2    |
+--------+--------+
|   1    |   3    |
+--------+--------+
|   2    |   1    |
+--------+--------+
|   2    |   2    |
+--------+--------+
```

The report I need should look like this:

```
+-----------+------------+
| prize_qty | player_qty |
+-----------+------------+
|      3    |      1     |
+-----------+------------+
|      2    |      1     |
+-----------+------------+
```

The Following code is close:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) as player_qty, prize_qty FROM 
(SELECT count( * ) AS prize_qty FROM `prizes` GROUP BY player)
as t1 GROUP BY player_qty
```

but it returns this:

```
+-----------+------------+
| prize_qty | player_qty |
+-----------+------------+
|      4    |      1     |
+-----------+------------+
|      2    |      1     |
+-----------+------------+
```

I need it to ignore that player #1 won prize #1  twice, but I'm not sure how further to illiminate duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said

> How players have won all 3 prizes, how many have won 2 prizes, etc..

and

> I need it to ignore that player #1 won prize #1 twice

So shouldn't you count players per prize after removing the fact that a player won the same prize more than once?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS player_qty, prize AS prize_qty
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT prize, player FROM prizes) AS T1
GROUP BY prize
```

Comment: You were just about there. the final result was this    SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) as player_qty, prize_qty FROM (SELECT count( * ) AS prize_qty 
FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT prize, player 
FROM `prizes` ) as t2 GROUP BY player) as t1 GROUP BY prize_qty

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) as player_qty, prize_qty FROM 
(SELECT count( * ) AS prize_qty FROM `prizes` GROUP BY player, prize)
as t1 GROUP BY player_qty
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(player) as player_qty, prize_qty FROM 
(SELECT count( distinct prize ) AS prize_qty, player FROM `prizes` GROUP BY player)
as t1 GROUP BY prize_qty
```